# C++11 std::is_convertible behaviour with private copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, std, language-lawyer, type-traits

I'm trying to understand `std::is_convertible` in C++11. According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), `std::is_convertible<T,U>::value` should evaluate to 1 iff "If an imaginary rvalue of type `T` can be used in the return statement of a function returning `U`". The wording says nothing about where that function might be declared, though. What should one expect when the copy constructor of `U` is private? What should one expect when `T` is an lvalue reference?

E.g., consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
struct Fact_A;
struct A {
    friend struct Fact_A;
    A() = default;
    A(A&&) = delete;
private:
    A(const A&) = default;
};
struct Ref_A {
    A* _ptr;
    Ref_A(A* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) {}
    operator A& () { return *_ptr; }
};
struct Fact_A {
    static A* make_A(const A& a) { return new A(a); }
    static A f(A* a_ptr) { return Ref_A(a_ptr); }
    //static A g(A&& a) { return std::move(a); }
};
int main() {
    A a1;
    A* a2_ptr = Fact_A::make_A(a1);
    (void)a2_ptr;
    std::cout << std::is_convertible< Ref_A, A >::value << "\n"  // => 0
              << std::is_convertible< Ref_A, A& >::value << "\n" // => 1
              << std::is_convertible< A&, A >::value << "\n";    // => 0
}
```

I'm using `gcc-4.8.2` or `clang-3.4` (no difference in output), and I compile with:

```
{g++|clang++} -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra eg.cpp -o eg
```

Here, `std::is_convertible< Ref_A, A >` reports `0`. However, you can see that `Fact_A::f` returns an object of type `A`, and an rvalue of type `Ref_A` is used in its return statement. The problem is that the copy constructor of `A` is `private`, so that function cannot be placed anywhere else. Is the current behaviour correct with respect to the standard?

Second question. If I remove `private`, the output turns into `1 1 1`. What does the last `1` mean? What is an "rvalue of type `A&`"? Is that an rvalue reference? Because you might notice I explicitly deleted the move constructor of `A`. As a result of this, I cannot declare `Fact_A::g`. But still, `std::is_convertible< A&, A >` reports `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is_convertible` is defined as follows in [meta.rel]/4 from n3485:

> Given the following function prototype:
>
> ```
> template <class T> typename
> add_rvalue_reference<T>::type create();
> ```
>
> the predicate condition for a template specialization `is_convertible<From, To>`
>   shall be satisfied if and only if the return expression in the following code would be
>   well-formed, including any implicit conversions to the return type of
>   the function:
>
> ```
> To test() {
>     return create<From>();
> }
> ```

and here, you need a movable/copyable `To`: The return-statement applies an implicit conversion, and this requires an accessible copy/move constructor if `To` is a class type (`T&` is not a class type).

Compare to [conv]/3

> An expression `e` can be implicitly converted to a type `T` if and only if the declaration `T t=e;` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`.

---

If `From` is `T&`, you get something like

```
To test() {
    return create<T&>();
}
```

which, similar to `std::declval`, is an lvalue: The expression `create<T&>()` is/yields an lvalue, since `T& &&` (via `add_rvalue_reference`) is collapsed to `T&`.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In addition to what you said, there is more text directly below the draft part you quoted, which specifically mentions context issues. I'll accept this. I guess what remains is a lingering question of whether the standard is doing the right thing. What I don't like is that, `is_convertible` seems unnecessarily tied to the constructor accessibility of `To`, which has nothing to do with `From`, or the relation between `From` and `To`. I can imagine situations where I really want to know if the conversion can be done in a context of my choosing...

Comment: @MateiDavid `is_convertible` tries to simulate the definition of *implicitly convertible*, which I find a bit unintuitive. That definition itself requires an accessible copy/move constructor. Maybe in your context, `is_constructible` makes more sense.